# APK file cannot be installed

Tags: android, installation, apk, device

I can't install an app on a device
Show me a message "There was a problem parsing the package"
the device name "urovo"
Site address ::  https://en.urovo.com/product/moiblebrcomputer.html

Comment: please specify which app (.apk) you are installing

Comment: I programmed it in android studio